# grep command to search a file from sub directory

Tags: grep

i have a directory `d1/` which contain two sub-directories `d2/` and `d3/`.

Directory `d2/` contains a number of files

I want to search a file from the `d3/` directory by matching a pattern in any of the directories using `grep` command.

Thanks

Comment: And what is your problem? Why do you tell us about `d1` and `d2` if you only want to find files in `d3`? Edit your question to include this!

Comment: @Panki i want the search the the file while working from d3 directory which is present in d2

Comment: And you need `grep` because you are trying to match the contents of the file? Or are you just trying to find a file with a specific name?

Comment: You mention that `d2` contains a few files, but then you want to search for a file in `d3`? How are the other directories relevant?  Please clarify your question by editing it (not by writing comments).

Comment: @Panki  d1 is the parent directory for the d1 and d2 and  i have a number of files in d2 directory and  i want to search a file with a pattern in any of the directories present.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would do the job

```
find ../d2 -type f -exec grep -H 'patern' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need find word in file, use (grep -rw):

```
grep -rw 'word from file' /etc/ | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```